# My python text files are not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't see how this code is not working. Can you help?

Here is my code so far:

```
import math
while True:
    message = input("Enter a message :")
    code1 = input("Enter a first code word :")
    code2 = input("Enter a second code word :")
    newmessage = ""
    new = ""
    listM = [(ord(m.lower())- 96) for m in message]
    listC1 = [(ord(c1.lower())- 96) for c1 in code1]
    listC2 = [(ord(c2.lower())- 96) for c2 in code2]
    messagec1 = math.ceil(len(listM) / len(listC1))
    messagec2 = math.ceil(len(listM) / len(listC2))
    newlistC1 = listC1 * messagec1
    newlistC2 = listC2 * messagec2
    adding1 = [listM[i] + newlistC1[i] for i in range(0,len(listM))]
    adding2 = [adding1[i] + newlistC2[i] for i in range(0,len(adding1))]
    finallist = [(adding2[i] + 96) for i in range(0,len(adding2))]
    for i in range(0,len(finallist)):
        newmessage += chr(finallist[i])
    print("In the text file called message")
    textfile = open("message.txt","w")
    textfile.write(newmessage)
    textfile.close()
    choice = input("would you like to decrypt aswell? (if you do type yes)")
    if choice == "yes":
        textfile = open("message.txt","r")
        textfileM = textfile.readlines()
        textfile.close
        listM = [(ord(str(m))- 96) for m in textfileM]
        taking1 = [listM[i] - newlistC2[i] for i in range(0,len(listM))]
        taking2 = [taking1[i] - newlistC1[i] for i in range(0,len(listM))]
        decryption = [(taking2[i] + 96) for i in range(0,len(taking2))]
        for i in range(0,len(decryption)):
            new += chr(decryption[i])
        print(new)
```

When i run this code it outputs:

```
Enter a message :hello
Enter a first code word :hi
Enter a second code word :cow
In the text file called message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\TASK £ TEXT FILES TEST.py", line 22, in <module>
    textfile.write(newmessage)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8b' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Looks like you have some non-ASCII text in your input file, no?

Comment: What would I need to to get it to work?

Comment: What are codecs? sorry I am quite new to python

Comment: Where would I put that? At the start?

Comment: when you open the file

Comment: It is coming up with a syntax error

Comment: It now is coming up with:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\TASK £ TEXT FILES TEST.py", line 23, in <module>
    textfile.write(newmessage)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: I was talking about reading from it, if you want to write then open with `w`

Comment: `open("message.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: You also never close the file `textfile.close -> textfile.close()`, one good example of why you should open your files using `with`

Comment: The comer before the "w" is coming up with a syntax error

Comment: Have you copy pasted the line above?

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. As I commented you should really use `with` to open your files

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the codecs library and open your file with it. It should work.

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-8')
f.write(your_data)
```

You can also set it as a "global" configuration for that module:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Then read the file as you are reading.

I also recommend you to read this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html